# Typescript: undefined is stripped from interface

Tags: typescript, interface, undefined

I really do not get why `undefined` disappears:

```js
export interface IPayloads {
  Test1: number | undefined;
  Test2: number | void;
  Test3?: number;
}

type t1 = IPayloads["Test1"];  // number
type t2 = IPayloads["Test2"];  // number | void
type t3 = IPayloads["Test3"];  // number
```

Where did `undefined` go (and why) on `t1` and `t3`?!?

Comment: How are you checking that the undefined is disappearing? I just tested this code in the TS playground, and hovering over t1 and t3 shows the type correctly as `number | undefined`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=41#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAVMBPAGwkwBMBnOAbwCg44AVYGmARgC44kArgFsARmjgAfOAKRVg6ZMCoBuZmw4wATH0GjxUgG4QEKte04BmAPw7hYqKoC+jRjBJg83OAF4CxcpS0ANoARObcIQC6yiwA9LH8dmiu7p6aPn6kFNQ0oeGaUTFw8Yl6UJJwRiYpHnAwFhlEWYG5YRoWhXEJuvZAA

Comment: Same for me in VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in the TS Playground and it reports the type correct as `number | undefined` for both types: `t1` and `t3`. See [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=41#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAVMBPAGwkwBMBnOAbwCg44AVYGmARgC44kArgFsARmjgAfOAKRVg6ZMCoBuZmw4wATH0GjxUgG4QEKte04BmAPw7hYqKoC+jRjBJg83OAF4CxcpS0ANoARObcIQC6yiwA9LH8dmiu7p6aPn6kFNQ0oeGaUTFw8Yl6UJJwRiYpHnAwFhlEWYG5YRoWhXEJuvZAA).

In **VS Code**, I had to enable `"strictNullChecks": true` in the `compilerOptions` section of `tsconfig.json` to get the correct type to show up.